# In SAS, does the using the GLS option 'absorb' invalidate the standard errors of the parameter estimates?

Tags: sas, statistics, panel-data, standard-error

SAS provides a handy tool for handling GLM models with a large number of groups or fixed effects - "absorb" (PROC GLM; ABSORB). My understanding is that it factors the effect of the absorbed parameters out of the data before estimating the remaining parameters. It seems like this may invalidate the standard errors of the parameter estimates. The variance covariance matrix would not be calculated with the full set of parameters. Hence, we would be calculating the variance covariance matrix conditional on the absorbed parameters, where we would really want the unconditional variance. Am I misunderstanding what is going on here? I haven't found any good explanations in the help files.

Comment: Please clarify what PROC you are asking about. Is it `PROC GLM` with an `ABSORB` statement?

Comment: @Quentin, yes PROC GLM with an ABSORB statement. Edited

Comment: Your best bet is to either contact SAS Support or communities.sas.com. Or post at stats.stackexchange.com.  Questions that are statistical methodology take a while to get answered on here.

Comment: @Reeza, thanks for the suggestion. I have now posted the question here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/265486/in-sas-does-the-using-the-glm-statement-absorb-invalidate-the-standard-errors-o